# Populating ComboBox with XML file, code is not working

Tags: xml, vb.net, combobox

I have the following vb.net code and XML file. What I am trying to achieve is to add each TTN value to the `ComboBox` but I get no result. No errors just nothing. I have checked the XML file and it passes as error free. Could someone explain what's going wrong.

```
Dim xml_doc As New XmlDocument
Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim node As XmlElement
xml_doc.Load(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\Stock.xml")
nodelist = xml_doc.SelectNodes("Compelation/Data/TTN")
For Each node In nodelist
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(node.InnerText())
Next
```

XML file:

```
<COMPELATION>
    <Data>
        <TTN>FD33</TTN>
        <FJQ>3</FJQ>
        <TTH>257,85</TTH>
        <TTW>290</TTW>
        <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
        <MTD>50</MTD>
        <MTT>2</MTT>
        <DVB>20</DVB>
        <TVB>2</TVB>
        <DTP>12</DTP>
        <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
        <TSW>0,044</TSW>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <TTN>FD34</TTN>
        <FJQ>4</FJQ>
        <TTH>290</TTH>
        <TTW>290</TTW>
        <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
        <MTD>50</MTD>
        <MTT>2</MTT>
        <DVB>20</DVB>
        <TVB>2</TVB>
        <DTP>12</DTP>
        <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
        <TSW>0,058</TSW>
    </Data>
</COMPELATION>
```

Comment: FWIW - In writing my answer I verified that the XML you posted is correct.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    Dim doc As XElement
    XElement.Load(IO.Path.Combine(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory, "Stock.xml"))

    Dim ttnNodes As IEnumerable(Of String) = From xe As XElement In doc.<Data>.<TTN>
                                               Select xe.Value

    ComboBox1.DataSource = ttnNodes.ToList
```

To test this I used this instead of loading the file

```
    doc = <COMPELATION>
              <Data>
                  <TTN>FD33</TTN>
                  <FJQ>3</FJQ>
                  <TTH>257,85</TTH>
                  <TTW>290</TTW>
                  <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
                  <MTD>50</MTD>
                  <MTT>2</MTT>
                  <DVB>20</DVB>
                  <TVB>2</TVB>
                  <DTP>12</DTP>
                  <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
                  <TSW>0,044</TSW>
              </Data>
              <Data>
                  <TTN>FD34</TTN>
                  <FJQ>4</FJQ>
                  <TTH>290</TTH>
                  <TTW>290</TTW>
                  <FCT>SC1-CON</FCT>
                  <MTD>50</MTD>
                  <MTT>2</MTT>
                  <DVB>20</DVB>
                  <TVB>2</TVB>
                  <DTP>12</DTP>
                  <MAT>6082 T6</MAT>
                  <TSW>0,058</TSW>
              </Data>
          </COMPELATION>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work for you:

```
nodelist = xml_doc.SelectNodes("COMPELATION/Data/TTN")
```